# Is there a simple way to know the datatype of a variable in Python?

Tags: python

How can I find the datatype of a variable in Python as auto datatypes are mentioned in python?

Comment: `type(variable_name)`

Comment: Please verify first before posting your question , if the same has been answered or not.

Answer (score 3):

To find the type of a variable, in python you can use the `type(variable)` method.

Answer (score 2):

yep, this:

```
foo = 1
print(type(foo))
```

results in:

```
<class 'int'>
[Finished in 0.1s]
```